# JSON parser and analyzer

Tags: json

I have a large JSON file made up of a regular listing of fields, such as:

```
{
   "objects":{
      "Foo":{
         "id":"3324",
         "size":"10kb",
         "enabled":"ENABLED"
      },
      "Bar":{
         "id":"5313",
         "size":"1mb",
         "enabled":"DISABLED"
      }
   }
}
```

I am looking for an online tool or library which can analyze such a regular JSON structure and provide a listing of:

Here's all of the object fields: "id", "size", "enabled"

Here all of the observed values: 
* "size" : "10kb", "1mb"
* "enabled": "ENABLED", "DISABLED"

For a simple example like this, it is easy enough to write one; but I am looking for a solution if the structure is regular but not necessarily known ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Try simple Python code for this case:

```
import json

with open('your_file.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

Next step is to iterate over *data* object as over normal dictionary:

```
keys = []
values = []

for obj in data['objects']:
    for key, value in obj.items():
        keys.append(key)
        values.append(value)

print keys, values
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As noted above, I'm interested in dealing with an unknown (but regular) structure. So perhaps there is nesting 5 levels deep in the JSON structure. At each level I would like to analyze the structure. So I need something similar to your solution, but can work on an arbitrarily-deep JSON structure.

Comment: Why don't you use a recurrence for example? Should do the trick in your case.